# How does cherry pick works in Azure devops

Tags: git

I have three feature branches: `F1`, `F2`, `F3`

All of them raised a Pull Request and merged into the `Development` branch.

Now I want to Merge only two of the features (`F1` & `F3`) from the `Development` branch to the `Release` branch.

Any suggestions?

I guess git cherry-picking works, but not sure how to work on it.
Please suggest any other alternatives, or explain cherry-picking if it suits my requirements.

Comment: Hi Stella, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that jessehouwing suggested? Were you able to resolve? If the reply helped and solved your issue. Appreciate for marking it as an answer,  which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't specific to Azure DevOps. It's a pure git problem. You have multiple options at this point.

### 1. Cherry picking may work.

Depending on how the feature branches were merged, you [could cherry-pick only the changes that merged F1 and F3](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). This may be tricky if F2 has touched the same files as F3.

### 2. Creating a new branch to merge to release

Creating a branch from 'develop' just before F1&2&3 were merged and merging F1 and F3 in that new branch, then merging that into master.

### 3. Reverting F2 in develop

[Compensate the changes introduced by F2 by reverting them](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) on 'develop' and then merging that into master.

### 4. Interactive rebase of develop.

You could change the history of the develop branch through an interactive rebase. In the rebase operation, drop the changes introduced by F2. Then either force push to 'develop' or push a new branch prior to merging with master.

---

In the end it may not be a git problem after all. But a planning problem. Why was F2 merged in the first place? What happened that caused it to be discarded further in the process? Why was F3 merged prior to accepting F2?